# I have to update all the rows of a Column in a table. Here is my query

Tags: mysql, select, update

So My tables are

**People:**

```
People_name(VARCHAR 100), 
People_id (INT, PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT)
```

**Tracks:**

```
Track_id(INT PRIMARY KEY), 
People_id_references (int ,Foreign key references People(people_id)), 
Track_title(VARCHAR 100)
```

**top100:**

```
artist varchar(100), 
id(int, primary key), 
track_title(varchar100)
```

All the columns in above tables are having values, except in people_id_references(this is in `tracks` table). `top100` has many other columns, but for the sake of clarity I did not mention them, and it is no way connected to `people` or `tracks` tables. The data from `top100` is present in `track` and `people` tables, this is done using some insert queries. I want to import values from `people_id` (it is in `People` table).

So my query is:

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET People_id_Reference = (SELECT People_id 
                           FROM People 
                           RIGHT JOIN top100 
                           ON 
                           People_name=top100.artist LIMIT 1) 
                           WHERE People_id_Reference IS NULL;
```

But that inserts same `people_id` into all rows of `People_id_Reference`. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please add your table structure in your question with sample data.

Comment: Unless there is a trigger on `tracks`, your `UPDATE` will never insert new rows into the table.  Could you show a few sample rows from `tracks` and `people`, showing what do you want to update, and what would be the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tracks t 
INNER JOIN top100 t1 ON t.track_title = t1.track_title 
LEFT JOIN People p ON t1.artist = p.People_name 
SET t.People_id_Reference = p.People_id 
WHERE t.People_id_Reference IS NULL;
```